# Forcing HyperV to mount an AVHDX file it thinks is corrupt

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2, avhdx

I have an AVHDX file that is part of a broken snapshot chain.  However, I'm fairly certain there will be useful contiguous data on the last AVHDX in the chain, if I can run forensic tools on it.  I have a tool under a Linux VM ready, and want to attach the AVHDX as a new IDE drive, but HyperV tells me it's corrupted when I try to click OK in the Settings dialog of the VM.  Is there some way to force it to accept the AVHDX despite corruption and still have it boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to get Hyper-V to mount just that partial snapshot file.

But your linux forensic tools should be able to operate on a file just as well as they do on an IDE drive.  One of the beautiful things about linux is that it treats everything like a file.  Just copy the file itself to the linux VM and work on it from there.

You may need to use the ''losetup'' command in linux to create a loopback and mount the file as a virtual disk, if your tools can't operate directly on the file.